# Multiple linkage of boost libraries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, linker

Is there can be a problem like ODR if application link with some libraries of boost and another library that compiled with link with boost?

Example:
`foo.exe` link with `boost-*.lib` and `bar.lib`, previously when compiling `bar.lib` it was link with `boost-*.lib` too.

Libraries build as Multi-threaded in terms of MSVC.

Comment: What type of library do you mean? Static or dynamic (DLL)? There is no link concept for a static library.

Comment: I ask about static libraries

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with libcURL and OpenSSL with static linking. The libCURL library uses OpenSSL for https download, and needs to link to OpenSSL when compiling it. My observation is:

- If you link libcURL to OpenSSL, then you don't need to link your program to OpenSSL when it uses libCURL
- If you link libcURL to OpenSSL and **also** link your program to OpenSSL, MSVC will complain that multiple and conflicting implementations exist.

What I recommend is that you try to link to `bar.lib` without that boost library, and see if it works. If it compiles, you're good without it. If you get an undefined reference error, then you need to link to it. That's the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing multiple versions of Boost (including header only libraries) in the same process is always a bad idea. Boost provides no API nor ABI guarantees, if two differing versions ever touch one another then expect memory corruption and worse.